# I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column, 1st column should start and End with below format

Tags: linux, awk

I want to check the numbers in the 1st column is equal to 2nd column, and 1st column should be starting with "ABC" and ending with "DEF" but some times it ends with "DEFZ#" numbers between "ABC"######"DEF" or "DEFZ#" should be matching to 2nd column. can anyone help me here please.

**My input:**

```
>ABC12345DEF | 12345  |23132331331|
>ABC12345DEFZ1 | 12345  |23132331331|
>ABC12345DEFZ2 | 12345  |23132331331|
>ABC95678DEF | 45678  |23132331331| 
>ABC87887DEF | 86187  |23132331331|
>ABC89043DEF | 89043  |23132331331|
>ABC89043DEFZ1 | 89043  |23132331331|
>ABC89043DEFZ2 | 89043  |23132331331|
>ABC89043DEFZ3 | 89043  |23132331331|
```

**Output Should be:**

```
>ABC12345DEF |12345 |23132331331|

>ABC12345DEFZ1 |12345 |23132331331|

>ABC12345DEFZ2 |12345 |23132331331|

>ABC89043DEFZ1 |89043 |23132331331|

>ABC89043DEFZ2 |89043 |23132331331|

>ABC89043DEFZ3 |89043 |23132331331|
```

I'm trying to use the following one, but it's not working. 
`awk -F '|' '"ABC" $2 "DEF"  != $1 { print }' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, there should not be asterisks `**` and `<` in your edit (formatting wrappers)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, thank you. I have edited it now.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, ok, but `>` signs should also be removed

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F' *\\| *' '{ match($1,/[0-9]+/) }substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)==$2' OFS='|' WHTFile.txt
```

The output:

```
ABC12345DEF |12345 |23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ1 |12345 |23132331331|
ABC12345DEFZ2 |12345 |23132331331|
ABC89043DEF |89043 |23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ1 |89043 |23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ2 |89043 |23132331331|
ABC89043DEFZ3 |89043 |23132331331|
```

---

***Bonus*** solution using ***sed*** expression:

```
sed -E '/^ABC([0-9]+)DEF[^\s|]*\s*\|\s*\1/!d' WHTFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"|" '
$1 ~ /^ABC[0-9]+DEF[123Z]/ || $1 ~ /^ABC[0-9]+DEF/{
   sub(/ +$/,"",$2);
   match($1,/[0-9]+/);
   if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)==$2){
     print
}
}
' OFS="|"  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I've tried it whole input it coming as output